# How to append a tuple to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I append a tuple to a list? I am trying following:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(tuple((str("{0}".format(5000)))))
>>> a
[('5', '0', '0', '0')]
```

Expected output is:

```
[('5000')]
```

Can someone help me fixing this issue?

Comment: `a.append(tuple((str("{0}".format(5000)),)))` - notice the comma

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to append a tuple of only a single element? Note that ``[('5000')]`` is the same as ``['5000']``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a one-value tuple use the notation `(value, )`, also no need use the `str`, `"".format()` **is** a `string`

```
a.append(("{0}".format(5000),))
```

Regarding the format you use, just do

```
a.append((str(5000),))
```

---

If we decompose it

```
t = ("{0}".format(5000),)
a.append(t)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because python does not allow you to create a single element tuple directly. You must use one comma for this.

For example:

```
my_tuple = (100) #It's integer
my_tuple = (100,) #It's tuple
```

Try this for your code:

```
a.append(tuple((str("{0}".format(5000)),)))
```